# SQL: return the select value in the stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have stored procedure with 3 statements to update sta_fk_col_id in the `status`  table. For test porpuses, I want to return the value in sta_fk_col_id without updating the table. Instead of `UPDATE status SET sta_fk_col_id =` I tried to do something like `SET valido =` but without seccuss.

SET valido

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tpcroot`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_test_store_procedure`(IN functionId INT, out valido int)
BEGIN
-- statement 1.1
SET valido = 
(SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(mon_alertlevel) >= 60 THEN 3 WHEN MAX(mon_alertlevel) < 60
AND MAX(mon_alertlevel) >= 30 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS color
FROM monitor INNER JOIN monitor_system ON fk_mon_id = mon_funct_id
WHERE fk_dri_id IN (110))
WHERE sta_fk_dri_id = (110);

-- statement 1.2
SET valido = 
(SELECT  color FROM ( SELECT MAX(sta_fk_col_id) AS color FROM status WHERE sta_fk_mty_id = 1
 AND sta_fk_sys_id = 4 
 AND sta_fk_dri_id IS NOT NULL) helptable) 
WHERE sta_fk_sys_id = 4 AND 
sta_fk_mty_id = 1 AND sta_fk_dri_id IS NULL;


-- statement 2
SET valido = (SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(mon_alertlevel) >= 60 THEN 3 WHEN MAX(mon_alertlevel) <60 AND MAX(mon_alertlevel) >= 30 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END AS color 
FROM monitor_system INNER JOIN monitor ON fk_mon_id = mon_funct_id  AND mon_funct_id = functionId) 
WHERE sta_fk_mty_id = 1 AND 
sta_fk_sys_id = 4 AND 
sta_fk_dri_id IS NULL AND 
(SELECT countDrilldown FROM (select Count(*) AS countDrilldown FROM status 
WHERE sta_fk_mty_id = 1 AND 
sta_fk_sys_id = 4 AND sta_fk_dri_id IS NOT NULL) helptable) = 0;

select @valido; 
END
```

I am calling the stored procedure like this:

```
CALL sp_test_store_procedure(2315, @returnValue);
select @returnValue;
```

Comment: Where do you do `SET valido = ...` in the procedure?

Comment: I don't see where @valido is assigned a value.

Comment: You said you don't want to update the table. But you have 3 `UPDATE` queries in the procedure. It looks like you posted the original version, not the test version that returns instead of updating.

Comment: @Barmar I have not add it because it did not work. I have updated my code.

Comment: You're reassigning `valido` for each query. You'll only return the last one.

Comment: Your parentheses in 1.2 aren't correct. And you can't refer to columns like `sta_fk_sys_id` in the outer query, it can only refer to columns returned by the subquery's `SELECT`.

Comment: You don't need `(SELECT countDrilldown FROM ...)` You can just use the inner `(SELECT COUNT(*) ...)` subquery there.

Comment: @Barmar the reason why I am assign valido 3 times because the update queries in the orginal code  is being run behind each other. It is just for testing to see which value it have at the end.

Comment: But your queries aren't using the previous value of `valido`. So you're not emulating the way the update queries build on each other.

Comment: @Barmar: you are right but how can I emulate it in my case? Should I  return 3 out values?

Comment: It's hard to say since you've removed the original `UPDATE` code from the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242422/discussion-between-tree-and-barmar).

Comment: Note that in MySQL, `valido` and `@valido` are not the same variable.